Can 501(c)(4)s donate to political candidates' campaigns?
Can 501(c)(4) non-profits fund political candidates' campaigns?
Unlike a 501(c)(3), 501(c)(3)s can engage in political activity, endorse candidates, etc.

The question could be greatly improved by specifying what 501(c)(4) means. Not everyone knows all laws by heart.

Yes, if it is not their primary function. The money may not be exempt from income tax though. See the IRC Sec. 501, Sec. 527. See this IRS presentation on the topic.
